# "0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float" though I think it returns float

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Entire code and the error can be seen here -
https://www.kaggle.com/pradhyo/keras-style-transfer-different-losses/data?scriptVersionId=9726696 (error is around 60% into the page - long section with black background)

I think the issue is _loss below seems to be double even though wd_float() returns float.

I tried returning int from wd_float() and also tried casting to int in style_loss_wasserstein() just to see what happens and the error became "0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is int, but expects float". So my best guess is tf.py_func is somehow converting the output from wd_float to double.

```
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html
# wasserstein_distance is supposed to return float based on docs
def wd_float(x, y):
    _wd = wasserstein_distance(x, y)
    return float(_wd)


def style_loss_wasserstein():
    ...
    _loss = tf.py_func(wd_float, [style_features, combination_features], tf.float32)
    _loss = K.cast(_loss, dtype='float32')
    print(f"first loss: {_loss}")
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(_loss, tf.float32)


...



from keras import backend as K
from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b


class Evaluator(object):
    ...
    def eval_loss_and_grads(self, x):
        ...
        outs = self.f_outputs([x]) # line causing the error
        loss_value = outs[0]
        ...

    def loss(self, x):
        assert self.loss_value is None
        loss_value, grad_values = self.eval_loss_and_grads(x)
        self.loss_value = loss_value
        self.grad_values = grad_values
        return self.loss_value          



outputs = [style_loss_wasserstein]
f_outputs = K.function([combination_image], outputs)
evaluator = Evaluator(f_outputs, img_nrows, img_ncols)



x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x.flatten(),
                                 fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
```

Here is the stack trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-fcc21e1fc999> in <module>()
     13                loss_fn,
     14                iterations,
---> 15                save_every)
     16 
     17 # Display each output iteration for a style

<ipython-input-16-2397e37b5e4f> in style_transfer(base_image_path, style_reference_image_path, result_prefix, loss_fn, iterations, save_every)
     47     for i in range(iterations):
     48         x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x.flatten(),
---> 49                                          fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
     50         print('Iteration ' + str(i) + ' loss value:', min_val)
     51         # save current generated image

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0, fprime, args, approx_grad, bounds, m, factr, pgtol, epsilon, iprint, maxfun, maxiter, disp, callback, maxls)
    197 
    198     res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,
--> 199                            **opts)
    200     d = {'grad': res['jac'],
    201          'task': res['message'],

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, **unknown_options)
    333             # until the completion of the current minimization iteration.
    334             # Overwrite f and g:
--> 335             f, g = func_and_grad(x)
    336         elif task_str.startswith(b'NEW_X'):
    337             # new iteration

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in func_and_grad(x)
    283     else:
    284         def func_and_grad(x):
--> 285             f = fun(x, *args)
    286             g = jac(x, *args)
    287             return f, g

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    291     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    292         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 293         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    294 
    295     return ncalls, function_wrapper

<ipython-input-14-687064fde378> in loss(self, x)
     29     def loss(self, x):
     30         assert self.loss_value is None
---> 31         loss_value, grad_values = self.eval_loss_and_grads(x)
     32         self.loss_value = loss_value
     33         self.grad_values = grad_values

<ipython-input-14-687064fde378> in eval_loss_and_grads(self, x)
     19         else:
     20             x = x.reshape((1, self.img_nrows, self.img_ncols, 3))
---> 21         outs = self.f_outputs([x])
     22         loss_value = outs[0]
     23         if len(outs[1:]) == 1:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2919                     return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2920 
-> 2921             return self._call(inputs)
   2922         else:
   2923             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2877             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2878         else:
-> 2879             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2880         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2881 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float
     [[{{node PyFunc}} = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Reshape_20/_609, Reshape_21/_611)]]
     [[{{node PyFunc/_613}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_103_PyFunc", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Could you post the full code? It's hard to help you otherwise

Comment: @Colonder I added some more code and the stack trace. The entire code is in the link above but I believe I have all the relevant code pasted into the question.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem today but inside a custom loss function in TF2.

For me, the solution was to convert the data using np.ndarray.astype function to np.float32 type before returning it inside my custom numpy function, so for example:

```py
def custom_loss_function_loss2(y_true, y_pred):
   loss = np.random.random(50)
   return np.ndarray.astype(loss, np.float32)

@tf.function
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
   loss1 = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
   loss2 = tf.numpy_function(custom_loss_function_loss2, [y_true, y_pred], np.float32)
   return loss1 + loss2
```

Hope that help other people in the future with the same kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the TensorFlow argument values leave the tensorflow graph as int, but you try to return to the graph using float. Changing the argument in tf.py_func from `tf.float32` to `tf.int` (or `tf.int32`, whatever works in pyhton) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem when I use the py_func function in tensorflow.

I solve it by modify np.float to np.float32