# Return value of pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, casting, dtype

I am currently trying to better understand Tensorflows CustomLayer feature. While implementing such a custom layer, I ran into the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py:110: UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to uint16
  "%s to %s" % (dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/skimage/exposure/exposure.py:307: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  image = (image - imin) / float(imax - imin)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float
         [[Node: model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/custom_image_op = PyFuncStateless[Tin=[DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3/_49)]]
         [[Node: model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/_55 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_126_model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](^_cloopmodel/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/NextIteration_1/_20)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 94, in <module>
    trainer.run(sess)
  File "/home//Downloads/dl_ss_19-master/Ex4/train/trainer.py", line 128, in run
    self._train_epoch(sess)
  File "/home/train/trainer.py", line 49, in _train_epoch
    self._model_is_training: True})
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float
         [[Node: model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/custom_image_op = PyFuncStateless[Tin=[DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3/_49)]]
         [[Node: model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/_55 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_126_model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](^_cloopmodel/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/NextIteration_1/_20)]]

Caused by op 'model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/custom_image_op', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 61, in <module>
    prediction_logits = model.pretrained(img_conc)
  File "/home/model/pretrained.py", line 56, in create
    x = CustomLayer(output_dim=(224, 224, 3))(inputs)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/keras/engine/topology.py", line 603, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/model/pretrained.py", line 41, in call
    res = tf.map_fn(preprocess_input, x)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 389, in map_fn
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2816, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2640, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2590, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 379, in compute
    packed_fn_values = fn(packed_values)
  File "/home/model/pretrained.py", line 30, in preprocess_input
    name='custom_image_op')
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 215, in py_func
    input=inp, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_script_ops.py", line 90, in _py_func_stateless
    "PyFuncStateless", input=input, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/local/tensorflow-1.4.0/python3.5/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float
         [[Node: model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/custom_image_op = PyFuncStateless[Tin=[DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3/_49)]]
         [[Node: model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/_55 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_126_model/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](^_cloopmodel/pretrained/custom_layer_1/map/while/NextIteration_1/_20)]]
```

Thus far I tried to cast the various parameters and change the arguments of the function. This however didn't influence the result at all. I am at a loss. Does someone have experience with pyfunc_0? If yes, how can I fix below's code?

Links I found useful:

https://github.com/cesc-park/attend2u/issues/2

https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/169

["0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float" though I think it returns float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278894/0-th-value-returned-by-pyfunc-0-is-double-but-expects-float-though-i-think-it)

[Including advanced computation (scikit-like) in a keras custom layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605021/including-advanced-computation-scikit-like-in-a-keras-custom-layer)

```
def equalize(img):
    img_adapteq = 255 * exposure.equalize_adapthist(img // 255)
    return img_adapteq.astype(np.float)


def preprocess_input(img):
    x = tf.py_func(equalize,
                   [img],
                   'float32',
                   stateful=False,
                   name='custom_image_op')
    return tf.cast(x, tf.float32)


class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.trainable = False
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        res = tf.map_fn(preprocess_input, x)
        res.set_shape([x.shape[0],
                       self.output_dim[1],
                       self.output_dim[0],
                       x.shape[-1]])
        return res

inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), tensor=x)
x = CustomLayer(output_dim=(224, 224, 3))(inputs)
```

Comment: You are returning a `float64` value from this `img_adapteq.astype(np.float)`. It should be float32 and everything will work fine

Comment: Thanks, @mlRocks! it worked for me in solving a similar problem!